# Understanding JCE Cipher Algorithm Strings

Tags: encryption, java

I am new to cryptographic ciphers and I am trying to understand the strings that JCE uses to specify cryptographic algorithms.  For example, using the documentation at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html

I understand that the string "PBEWITHMD5AND128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL" specifies Password-based encryption with and MD5 message digest and 128BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL encryption.  What I do not understand is how the digest (or pseudo-random function) relates to the encryption cipher and does the digest only apply to password-based encryption?

Comment: the password needs to be converted into an encryption key for the cipher

Comment: This is specific to Bouncy Castle. If there are several parts of the algorithm string then they are separated with forward slashes in the algorithm strings of the JCE, not with dashes as in this specific example. I would guess that this uses PBE using the `BytesToKey` password based key derivation specific to OpenSSL using MD5 as the underlying hash. The resulting key is then used for CBC encryption with PKCS#7 compatible padding.

Comment: Yes, the string I used was from Bouncy Castle, however JCE also has similar strings such as "PBEWithMD5AndDES".  If I understand you correctly, in this case, MD5 would be used to turn the password into a symmetric key use by DES?

Comment: Yep, that's it. It's a parameter for the Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF) which in turn is part of the PBE method used.